# Run multiple .py from another .py simultaneously with arguments and timeout

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, os.system, simultaneous

I have a program, let's say "main.py", which runs through the argument "python main.py 3" or, for example, "python main.py 47", which means running a specific ID inside the program itself.

I'm trying to write another script, let's say "start.py", so that it starts a certain number of such programs. If inside start.py I have written threads = 4, timeout = 5, then it should run "python main.py 1", "python main.py 2", "python main.py 3", "python main.py 4" at the same time, but with a delay of 5 seconds between each command.

I know how to do this in one thread, but no other arguments are run until the previous one completes.

```
threads = 4
id = 1
for i in range(threads):
    os.system(f"python main.py {id}")
    id += 1
    time.sleep(5)
```

I am trying to do this via multiprocessing, but I am failing. What is the best way to implement this, and am I going in the right direction?

I've already done this through bash, but I only need to do it in Python.

```
for ((i=1; i<=4; i++))
do
    python3 main.py "$i" &
done
```

Comment: Don't use `os.system()` to do this. Inside `main.py` ensure that there is a function `main()` that accepts a parameter. You can add such a function without any other changes to `main.py`. Then in `start.py` do `import main` and every time you want to start that function, do `main.main(1)` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to or can't make changes to *main.py*, then the simplest change you can make to your current code is to simply execute the `system` call in a thread so you do not block:

```py
from threading import Thread
import os
import time

def run_main(id):
    os.system(f"python main.py {id}")

threads = 4
id = 1
started_threads = []
for i in range(threads):
    if i != 0:
        time.sleep(5)
    t = Thread(target=run_main, args=(id,))
    t.start()
    started_threads.append(t)
    id += 1
for t in started_threads:
    t.join()
```

Note that I have moved the call to `time.sleep` since you were doing an extra call that you did not need.

But this is rather expensive in that you are starting a Python interpreter for each invocation of `main`. If I understand the comment offered by @BoarGules (although what he literally said would not run the function `main` 4 times in parallel but rather sequentially), the following is an alternative implementation if *main.py* is structured like the following:

```
import sys

def main(id):
    ... # process

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1])
```

And then your *start.py*, if running under Linux or some platform that uses fork to start new processes, is coded as follows:

```py
from multiprocessing import Process
import os
import time
import main

threads = 4
id = 1
started_processes = []
for i in range(threads):
    if i != 0:
        time.sleep(5)
    p = Process(target=main.main, args=(id,))
    p.start()
    started_processes.append(p)
    id += 1
for p in started_processes:
    p.join()
```

But if you are running under Windows or some platform that uses spawn to start new processes, then you must code *start.py* as follows:

```py
from multiprocessing import Process
import os
import time
import main

# required for Windows:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    threads = 4
    id = 1
    started_processes = []
    for i in range(threads):
        if i != 0:
            time.sleep(5)
        p = Process(target=main.main, args=(id,))
        p.start()
        started_processes.append(p)
        id += 1
    for p in started_processes:
        p.join()
```

And each new `Process` instance you create will end up running a new Python interpreter anyway, so you will not be saving much over the initial solution I offered.

**This is why when you post a question tagged with `multiprocessing` you are supposed to also tag the question with the platform.**

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer! The first code completely solved all my problems. When I decide to move on, I'll be sure to take the rest of the code for thought.